# What is this *::-moz-progress-bar and why does it come up in Firebug CSS?

Tags: css, firebug

Whenever I right click to inspect element in Firebug on Firefox, it gives me this "*::-moz-progress-bar" CSS listed before the element I inspected. Anyone know what this is and how to get rid of?

[image: Firebug Screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's an option on the Firebug `Style ▼` drop-down menu to [Show User Agent CSS](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Style_Side_Panel#Options_Menu), you must of accidentally enabled it recently.

Answer (score 0):

The current version of Firebug (reportedly started in version 1.11.3) has a bug where it incorrectly displays numerous User Agent CSS at the top of the list. If you've been using the "Show User Agent CSS" option for a while now and this problem just started, you're most likely experiencing this bug.

Give it some time, as the bug was only posted today (5/16/2013). Hopefully the Firebug developers will release a fixed version within a few days.

And as the other poster said, you can always disable the showing of all User Agent CSS. Though as stated in the bug report (link below), it may still appear in certain cases.

Bug Report: http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=6451

Bug Discussion: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/firebug/5vwmU-IEkbc